# Is there a rule of thumb for minimum sample size in PCA?

Tags: multiple-regression, pca

My input data has 200 dimension. But I don't have a lot of samples, probably 350

I feel that the sample size is too small, compared with the raw dimensional.

Is there a rule of thumb to estimate the minimum sample size?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question for which I have not seen answers.  Sometimes we learn by taking large sample examples where things work, and progressively subsampling until it breaks.  But you need to define a goal, e.g. how many PCs do you want to be accurate?  How to measure accuracy?  For your sample size you'd be lucky to estimate the first PC well.

Answer (score 1):

For classical methods, one rule of thumb you hear is to have at least ten times as many data points as descriptors. If you are using OLS regression you will overfit. This is referred to as the "curse of dimensionality".

However, you can do better than a rule of thumb. The issue is not the number of parameters (which for OLS is one per descriptor, plus one for the intercept). The issue is the VC dimension of the learning method.

The Support Vector Machine approach was designed for exactly the sort of problem you have, and is likely to give good results, if you can devise a suitable kernel.

Comment: I don't see why you mention SVM in the context of unsupervised learning.